# selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am working on selenium, while running Java code I tried to CLICK a menu from the web page but encounter error of `selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible` Kindly advise on this matters . Thanks you

HTML code for text field :

```
<li onclick="goin('pages/AbcProxy/proxyGroupList.do')>
 <a href="javascript::">TESTABC</a>
```

JAVA code:

```
WebdriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
wait until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/ul/li[12]/a")));
```

Answer (score 1):

`presenceOfElementLocated` checks if the element *exists* in the DOM. To check if the element is *visible* use `visibilityOfElementLocated`

```
WebdriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/ul/li[12]/a")));
element.click();
```

Comment: Hi , if i use the method of visibilityOfElementLocated does it effect unable to onclick this element ?

Comment: @JaydenNg this will return the element it was waiting for. If the element is visible it will get into `element` in my example. You can use it to send the click.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your xpath is to a different `a` element that is invisible (css display none or such).

It would be better to use some `id` first (maybe for the parent `ul`?) and then a relative xpath from there, full xpaths from root are not recommended as it makes the test very brittle

Comment: Hi @the-noob , do you mind show some example , as im stuck on this matters. Thanks you

Comment: For that I would need a bit more html, is there an `id` attribute for any of the parents of `a` ?